# How to put several ints into an int array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, int

here's the problem:

I have student Class:

```
class Student
{
    public int Mark1 { get; set; }
    public int Mark2 { get; set; }
    public int Mark3 { get; set; }
    public int Mark4 { get; set; }
    public int Mark5 { get; set; }
    public Student(int mark1, int mark2, int mark3, int mark4, int mark5)
    {
        Mark1 = mark1;
        Mark2 = mark2;
        Mark3 = mark3;
        Mark4 = mark4;
        Mark5 = mark5;
    }
}
```

And I need to put these marks of each student into an int array. Here are my attempts:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
    public static void MarksAbove5(College ListOfStudents, out College FilteredStudents)
    {
        FilteredStudents = new College(50);
        int[] Marks = new int[ListOfStudents.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < ListOfStudents.Count; i++)
        {
         Marks[i] = (ListOfStudents.GetStudent(i).Mark1, ListOfStudents.GetStudent(i).Mark2, ListOfStudents.GetStudent(i).Mark3, ListOfStudents.GetStudent(i).Mark4, ListOfStudents.GetStudent(i).Mark5);
        } 
    }
}
```

And I get an error stating "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement".
How do I put these ints into an int array correctly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you actually wanting an array of arrays or are you trying to flatten the marks of all students into a single array?

Comment: I want each student to have his/her own array of their own marks.
For example, John's marks: 
Mark1: 5
Mark2: 6
etc;
Johns Mark Array: 5,6, etc

I will be needing the mark array to check if all of the marks in that mark array are above 5

Comment: If that's the case you need a 2-dimensional array. int[][] marks = new int[ListOfStudents.Count][] and see the array initialization link.

Comment: Or since you know the number of marks int[,] marks = new int[ListOfStudents.Count, 5]

Comment: this is not a dup of the initialization question. Its simply a question about loading data into an array.

Comment: @Servy I agree this should not have been marked a dup

Comment: @npearson, yes I do know exactly how many marks will be there. There will be 5 marks for each person. 
So it should look like:
int[,] marks = new int[ListOfStudents.Count, 5]?
where does the "i" come in?
P.S. I am sorry, I am a beginner at c# and tomorrow is the programming exam, and I feel desperate :/

Comment: With the int[,] declaration you would need to add each mark individually. mark[i, 1] = ListOfStudents.GetStudent(i).Mark1;

Comment: Using the first declaration, it's exactly what you have but with the correct initialization using curly braces. marks[i] = new int[]  {ListOfStudents.GetStudent(i).Mark1, ...}

Comment: I did what you said in the last comment, but I get another error:
"Cannot implicitly convert type 'int[]' to 'int'"